# Challenge to iterate truncated md5 hash

Tags: loops, hash, truncated

i need an help to this challenge of programming.

> "With this string: NzQwZjgxMTU2YzI3NjM1NA==
>
> MD5 hash it and remove the last 16 characters of the hash. Iterate
> this process 50 times and submit the final truncated hash below."

What language can i use?
Anyone can explain me the script to do?

Comment: `md5` is hash algorithm, so basically any language can be used. Then you need to truncate it by removing 16 last symbols and re-hash again 50 times

Comment: yeah man i know it, for this reason i am asking the code to make this

Comment: `hash = ''; for (i = 1; i <= 50; i++) {hash = substring(md5(input), -16)}`

Comment: "What language can i use?" - any available. What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

```
import hashlib

originalhash = 'MGE0ZjFmODRhMTQ0ZTJjYQ=='
print(originalhash)
previous = hashlib.md5(original.encode('ascii')).hexdigest()
print(previous)

for i in range(50):
        text = previous[0:-16]
        print(text)
        nexthash = hashlib.md5(previous.encode('ascii')).hexdigest()
        print(nexthash)
        previous = nexthash
```